# Neo4J installation - StartService Failure

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to install Neo4j(1.8) but i faced a problem when starting the service.

after extracting the zip file I went directly to the bin folder and executed the batch file:

```
Neo4J.bat install
```

[SC] CreateService SUCCESS
[SC] StartService Failed 1053:
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

*I was so graphDB enthusiastic so I went to the shell and created new db hundreds of nodes and relationships and I spent nearly a week working on that shell, everything seems great, until I read about the WebService and the REST API so now I need the service to run. **RTFM Case!***

digging a bit... I found that I don't have **neo4j-server.properties** file into the conf directory, the questions:

1- is that file responsible for the service start failure?
2- should I build that file manually, and what are the mandatory params?
3- is this a normal behavior or the zip file was corrupted?

*PS: I tried to create the props file, as follows:*

```
org.neo4j.server.database.location=D:/Neo4J/db/Mydb/
org.neo4j.server.webserver.port=7474
org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0
wrapper.java.additional.3=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
org.neo4j.server.db.tuning.properties=neo4j.properties
```

***but the service refuse to start!***

Cheers,
Ob.

Comment: can you try to start with these properties and `neo4j.bat console` to see a bit more? If that is ok, then the service install is failing in some way ... what windows version?

Comment: @Peter executing 'neo4j.bat console' succeeded with no reply nor error message, going through the base.bat file I found that env. var %JAVA_HOME% is not configured on my machine so I added it, but still I cant start the service.
its a bit confusing.
tell me peter what java libraries should be installed other than JRE? 
I'm testing the installed service by this URL: 'http://127.0.0.1:7474/WebService/' is that correct? is there any other way?
Thanks in advance
_PS: running on Windows 7 W32x86._

Comment: So, if you start `neo4j.bat console` you should be able to see the webadmin at http://localhost:7474/ ?

Comment: Thank you @PeterNeubauer my problem is solved and I'm working on the webservice, appreciate ur follow up. cheers.

Answer (score 7):

In version 1.8.2 and using windows 8 I had the same problem:
I moved the install folder to

program files\neo4j

then took full access rights

and edited the bin\base.bat, where it said:

```
set wrapperJarFilename=windows-service-wrapper-*.jar
```

I changed to:

```
set wrapperJarFilename=windows-service-wrapper-4.jar
```

Now it works:

```
C:\Program Files\Neo4j\bin>Neo4j.bat install
[SC] CreateService SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: Neo4j-Server
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        STATE              : 2  START_PENDING
                                (NOT_STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x7d0
        PID                : 2936
        FLAGS              :

C:\Program Files\Neo4j\bin>
```

Uninstall also works

```
C:\Program Files\Neo4j\bin>Neo4j.bat uninstall

SERVICE_NAME: Neo4j-Server
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        STATE              : 3  STOP_PENDING
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, ACCEPTS_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x1388
[SC] DeleteService SUCCESS

C:\Program Files\Neo4j\bin>
```

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't install the neo4j 1.8 console until I created the neo4j directory within the program files folder, this sounds odd if you know that I'm running as administrator, i know its a privileges situation! but who cares, its running. (I hate windows sometimes).

Comment: Feel free to blog about your experiences and how you solved it - maybe we can improve the procedure or you can contribute some improvements?

Answer (score 1):

For 1.9 and windows 7, the re-installation to c:\program files also remedies the situation.

For 1.9 it is not necessary to change the wrapperJarFilename (it's already set to 5)