# Neo4j StartService FAILED 1053 after copying Beer DB example

Tags: neo4j

I installed Neo4j as instructed in the site and was able to install and stat server. However I tried to copy the Beer example DB by stopping the server and deleting the current graph.db in the \data folder and replaced with the one Beer example downloaded from online (graph.db folder). This is the only step I did.

Now the issue is, when i tried to start the Server I get "StartService FAILED 1053"

I am using following command on the powershell in windows - c:\neo4j-community-2.0.0-M03> .\bat\Neo4j.bat start

Can someone please help if I have done anything wrong here.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try searching before posting? [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576778/neo4j-startservice-failed-1053) || [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937846/neo4j-installation-startservice-failure?rq=1)

Comment: Yes I did and that did not solve my problem.like I said it worked fine before I copied the Beer example db.

Comment: Running the neo4j console doesn't work either?

Comment: Yes.. Console doesn't work as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running neo4j 2.0 against an older database file. You'll need to set the config parameter to allow the store to be upgraded before starting. See instructions here:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/deployment-upgrading.html#_explicit_upgrade